# Bootstrap Dropdown left / right position bug on mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have an incomprehensible problem in our web application. I have reduced the page to a minimum, here it is:

https://www.aschemeier.net/bug1.html

Everything works fine on the desktop. When I test the page either in the Firefox browser (screen size set to iPhone) or on an Android smartphone (Chrome browser), display errors occur when I open the drop-down menu at the bottom. In the mobile emulation on the desktop the touch input is registered after a few clicks about 200px further up, on the smartphone the picture jumps up and you can't scroll down anymore. If I reduce the height of the red framed container it works from a certain limit. If I don't open the menu to the left (dropleft) there are no problems either, but I need this function at this point.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Alle globalen, externen Javascript Dateien -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-1CmrxMRARb6aLqgBO7yyAxTOQE2AKb9GfXnEo760AUcUmFx3ibVJJAzGytlQcNXd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>bug sample</title>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mb-5 mt-4">





    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body" style="height:1000px; border:2px solid #f00;"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="mt-4">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-4">AB</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-4">AB</div>

        <div class="col-md-1 col-4">
          <!-- Split dropleft button -->
          <div class="btn-group">
            <div class="btn-group dropleft" role="group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropleft</span>
                            </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
                            Split dropleft
                          </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would handle it by assigning an `expander` class into the parent `row` and toggle `expander` class on each button click.

Sample CSS:

```
.expanded-row {
    min-height:30vh;
}
```

Toggling the class:

```
$( ".dropdown-toggle" ).click(function() {
  $( ".row" ).toggleClass( "expanded-row" );
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you. It helps a little bit... Now only every 4th oder 5th click destroys it. The strange is that the touch events are recognized on a complete different position after opening and closing the menu. Another problem is that it doesnt look that good....

And please edit your answer: heigth = height and "expanded-row" without "." thanks